# Why does it always display "No Insights Available" for my apps?

Tags: analytics, facebook-insights

We have launched several Facebook apps.  They are intended to run on Facebook Pages as tab-based iframe apps.  These apps have been installed on dozens of pages, have thousands of daily users.  Users who view these tabs do not need to authorize the apps, we don't require any permissions.  When users share through these apps, we use the Facebook JS dialogs library.

With the exception of one, all of these apps display "No Insights Available" when I try to view the insights data.  The only analytics we get from Facebook is the Insights summary page which includes some basic user, sharing and performance data - but no details are available.

As I mentioned, one app *does* have Insights.  It was the first app we launched on Facebook.  It was originally a canvas iframe app but now runs exclusively from profile pages.  This seems to be the only difference from our more recent apps.

So I guess my question is this: is Insights availability triggered by having users access your canvas app?  Or is there some other reason that we can not get Insights for all of our apps except the one original application?  As I mentioned, users are sharing from these apps and we would love to know more about the reaction those stories are getting.

(I filed a bug with Facebook but after an initial request for app ids and a promise to look into it, they have since stopped responding to my requests for an update.)

Comment: This is on topic enough, someone who had a similar experience might be able to answer this, thus creating a good reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, it turns out this was a Facebook bug that they have now fixed.  We weren't doing anything wrong.  The fact that one app had canvas page views and the other did not was purely coincidental.

On Wednesday, Facebook has deployed an updated version of Insights that integrates with their application page directly - and miraculously, we're able to see Insights data for all of our applications again, including historical data that Facebook previously listed as "No insights available."

If anyone is interested, here's their blog posting on the upgraded Insights application. https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/554/